# How is this program giving out these outputs? C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cin;

int main (){
long num1;
cin >> num1;
long num2;
cin >> num2;

 long cnt = 0;
 long temp = num1;
 long res = 0;

 while (cnt < num2){
 res = temp % 10;
 temp = temp / 10;
 temp = temp + (res * 100);
 cnt++;
 }
 cout << num1 << endl;  // Line 1
 cout << temp << endl;  // Line 2
 cout << cnt  << endl;  // Line 3
 }
```

I'm confused as to how this program is getting these outputs. Given **user input of 456 2**, line 2 should give back 564. Below is my work (problem 4). After running the calculations I get 624, why is it 564? The next problem I was attempting to do was user input: 789 3, after I saw my answer was gonna get in the thousands I assumed I was doing it wrong. **Please let me know if I am doing something wrong and how I can get an output of 564**. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Never include code as pictures (accessibility problems) or on an external site (the site may go down), instead copy the code into the question and format it as a code block.

Comment: Note that integral types truncate decimals. If `temp == 789` then `temp / 10` will yield 78, not 78.9

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains pictures of code.

Comment: @n.m. There is a difference between a poor quality question an off-topic question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**" (taken from the rules).

Comment: @tambre The question provides provides everything it needs to, but in an inconvenient format. In fact, this is the first time I've seen someone write what they expect the behavior to be with such detail.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux And by doing that the question can be closed off-topic, per the rule I quoted above.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux a question about non-working code should include the offending code in the body, otherwise it is off topic. A picture is not code (try to feed it to your compiler).

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought provided the output of the code was all I needed I can edit it and make it code.

Comment: @n.m. Someone with the motivation can answer this question, even if the picture makes it inconvenient. It can be meaningfully answered. It should be changed for the convenience of other users and to insure it's integrity should the image's hosting stop, but that doesn't make it off topic.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank you, I changed the image to the working code. Hope that helps! Didn't know I would face all this backlash I was just looking for someone to help me fix my math and didn't think the code was particularly relevant to be tested, but no biggie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, the difference between your calculations and the actual result is as follows

cnt 0:

res = 456 % 10 = 6

temp = 456 / 10 = 45

temp = 45 + (6*100) = 645

cnt 1:

res = 645 % 10 = 5

temp = 645 / 10 = 64

temp = 64 + (5*100) = 564

Integer division truncates off the remainder, which is the result of the mod operator. You had the decimal still there, which created a 60 out of nowhere when multiplied by 100

Just a good example of rounding issues when grown by a large factor! (100)

Comment: Thank you for your work, I'm glad I know I was doing it right, just I need to cut the remainder off. Much appreciation